# Regenerate session after a certain time and destroy it after a certain time

Tags: php, session

I have searched for a way to check if a session is started and how long has it been since it was started, and if passes half hour per say regenerate the id, if it passes more than an hour destroy it.

I found this code here on stack:

```
//Start the session
session_start();

// Check if the session is started, if not regenerate it each time passes 30 minutes
if (!isset($_SESSION['init'])) {
    $_SESSION['init'] = time();
} elseif (time() - $_SESSION['init'] > 1800) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['init'] = time();
}

//Check if the session was alive for more than one hour, if so kill it
if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > 3600)) {
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
```

But it seems to run is some problems, I tried destroying it after 18 seconds so I can check if it's working. When I request the page that is protected and it's been more than 18 seconds, the first time I'm still being on it but the second time I'm redirected as I am supposed to be the first time after 18 seconds, why is that ?

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: I assume that super global $_SESSION['init'] has some value, then if ( time() -  $_SESSION['init'] great than 1800 then the session will be regenerated (a new session id will be created!) and $_SESSION['init'] receives current UNIX timestamp. The second part do the same but do not regenerate the session id. But after your first and second IF the super global $_SESSION gains a new value current UNIX timestamp .. that is what it does! I really recommend you to read up this page -> http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: @Fernando - so it would be better to choose only to regenerate or to destroy and not both ?

Comment: | It really depends of your goal! But based in your question, looks like you will need to use both of them. Cause if greater than 1800 but not greater than 3600 you just need to regenerate the session, but if greater the 3600 you need to kill the session. The I assume that you need to use both of them.

Comment: What if I do the next: `if (!isset($_SESSION['init'])) {
    $_SESSION['init'] = time();
} elseif (time() - $_SESSION['init'] > 1800) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['init'] = time();
} elseif (time() - $_SESSION['init'] > 3600) {
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
` , wouldn't this way be better ?

Comment: Roland - The problem is, you need to store the session value, because you need to compare if it is greater than what you expect it to be. I always use database to store values when I need to compare something. In this case is not different. MySQL is a good option.

Comment: The above code will always give the last unix timestamp to $_SESSION['init'], then it will NEVER be greater then 1800 or 3600. Unless you compare a stored value ....

Comment: I see, well storing the values in the db isn't an option for me, I mean to what purpose ? I already have a db for users where I store usernames and passwords ( hashes ). I want to use the session for avoiding fixation and to regenerate it after a while or logout the user if more than an hour passes. So what if at the end of those lines I add `$_SESSION['init'] = time();` ?

Comment: @Fernando - This is what I want to do with the sessions. I want to start a session. And every time that half hour passes I need to regenerate it, and when more than an hour passes I need to destroy the session, because I want the user to be logged out when an hour passes so when he want's to do something and an hour passes he must login again to be able to do that something. I hope I'm clear now, and if so how can I acquire that ?

Comment: I have no idea how to control the time of session without store the intial time to compare without BD. Now if you want to kill all session after 1 hour just put this in the top of your script -> 
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "3600");

Comment: @Fernando - And how would I perform this with a database for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the page the first time, you check if a session is set and then at the end set the session variable. You should put the `$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();` at the beginning. Also, the page will not keep checking if a session variable is expired, so it will only check if you set the variable on one page and check/set it on all of the pages you want protected.